# have lunch, eat lunch

Tags: verbs, aspect, food

Most often you would interchangeably use either of the following, meaning you had an occasion of consuming the meal at that time.

1. I **had** lunch at two thirty.
2. I **ate** lunch at two thirty.

Now, if you closely looked at the length or speed of the eating action, and wanted to tell the listener that you consumed the food quickly, you would say 4 more often than 3.

3. I **had** lunch quickly.
4. I **ate** lunch quickly.

Then, **how about if you are to use 'a quick lunch'? I favor 5, and wouldn't tend to say 6 when careful. Am I on the right track?**

5. I **had** a quick lunch.
6. I **ate** a quick lunch.

Comment: Go for option 5 because you eat 'food' and lunch is *directly* not food, but a term for that. Adjective *quick* can be applied in such case to 'fasten' up the process. Say, *quick look..*

Comment: @Maulik then why are there so many results in Google Books for *ate a quick lunch*?

Comment: Both 5 and 6 are idiomatic.

Comment: @Clare it is almost at the bottom of the results on Ngram. 'Had a quick lunch' is way above it!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the idiomatic expression is

> **I had a quick lunch**.
>   *I grabbed a quick bite to eat for lunch*

in the same way

> We **had** a working lunch

The reason for #4 is the adverb "*quickly*"

> ate *quickly*

is much preferred over

> had *quickly*

Comment: While *had a quick lunch* is probably used more often, *ate a quick lunch* is also idiomatic. A Google book search verifies this.